# Calling an object declared in a function of one class from a function of another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop

I am in a function of class A(tableview controller) where I have an object of class B(UserDetails class).Something like:

```
-(void) connectionFinishedLoading:(NSURLConnection*) connection :(UserDetails *) user{

//some code
user=A;
}
```

I want to use the value of "user" object in a function(different from the Class A function)  of class C(table view controller).Something like:

```
 -(void)newfunction :(NSURLConnection*) connection{
 //I want to use the value of "user" here.
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best possible way to store a value and use it in various classes is to use property of appDelegate class.

create a property in your appDelegate class say NSString *user; synthesize it

Create an instance of AppDelegate in connectionDidFinishLoading like

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
appDelegate.user = A;
```

Further in

```
-(void)newfunction :(NSURLConnection*) connection{
 //I want to use the value of "user" here.
    YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.user);
  }
```

Comment: an extension of the above problem: connectiondidFinishLoading is called on the click of a button corresponding to each row in that view controller. And the data corresponding to that row has to be printed in class C(in the cellforRowatIndexPath method which gets called after the newfunction). And the printing should be such that if I click on two buttons, then the data corresponding to both the rows should be printed. However, I am not able to print both the data. the second data is getting overwritten by the first and only the latest data is getting printed.

Answer (score 1):

Store the object you need to use in different classes in a shared placeholder class like Singleton. Then simply get its shared instance and retrieve the object you need. Google a bit to get a pattern.